# Installing Minecraft on a 32-bit Xubuntu 18.04 LTS installation

Tags: xubuntu, dpkg, java, software-center, minecraft

Thanks in advance to anybody who is able to shine some light on this issue of mine. I have recently `Xubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Dell Optiplex 755`, and I've been having difficulty installing the Minecraft launcher.

I downloaded the `.deb package` from the Minecraft website, and I attempted to install it using the Software Center. After selecting "Install" and entering my credentials, the progress bar flashed quickly before disappearing and presenting me with the "Install" button again. I closed the Software Center, opened a terminal, and attempted to install my package with `sudo dpkg -i`. This time, it claimed that the `.deb` was a 64-bit package, which doesn't match my 32-bit system.

I was wondering if this is normal, as I'm sure that I've installed Minecraft on a 32-bit Windows system before. Also, whether or not this is normal, is the any way to install this package on my system?

EDIT: I downloaded MultiMC, thinking that maybe the launcher itself didn't support my 32-bit OS, and after installing it successfully and attempting to launch 1.13 from it, it crashed with the following report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Sorry :(

Time: 8/21/18 8:48 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl32.so
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:82)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:71)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:628)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:637)
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:126)
    at cfi.an(SourceFile:554)
    at cfi.am(SourceFile:433)
    at cfi.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:196)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:231)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:82)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:71)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:628)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:637)
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:126)
    at cfi.an(SourceFile:554)
    at cfi.am(SourceFile:433)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at cfi.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:196)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:231)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.13
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 4.15.0-20-generic
    Java Version: 1.8.0_181, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 493009496 bytes (470 MB) / 693633024 bytes (661 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
    Launched Version: MultiMC5
    LWJGL: 3.1.6 build 14
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: I did a quick google search of the first line of the crash-report, and discovered that LWJGL 3 doesn't support 32-bit Linux distros. I would imagine that that's the reason the minecraft launcher only supports 64-bit systems. If anybody happens to know what I could do to circumvent this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I know why u failed to launch minecraft 1.13. Minecraft doesn't support 32-bit starting 1.13 Here is how I knew this
https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-121388 Lots of people have this problem. :) (I have the same problem by the way lol)

Answer (score 0):

I just got Minecraft Pocket Edition (1.12.0.28 and 1.13.0.5 Beta) working with Minecraft Bedrock Launcher (https://mcpelauncher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on 32-bit Xubuntu 18.04. Compiled it from source code following instructions on that page and purchased Minecraft Pocket Edition from Google Play store. This Pocket Edition is a lot more responsive and faster than Java Edition (which was pretty much unusable on this same computer when it had 64-bit Ubuntu 19.10).