# Lubuntu 18.10 Minecraft install

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10, minecraft

How to install Minecraft launcher on Lubuntu 18.10.
Snap method doesn't seem to work anymore and the official tar.gz file from mojang hasn't any install procedure text in it.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes. I have seen this method too. The .deb package can't be installed. I have installed gdebi-core too. When i perform the $ sudo gdebi ~/Minecraft.deb command an error message appears in terminal.

Comment: When i run this command it says that such file (minecraft.deb) doesn't exist, which is false. The file is in desktop. Tried using the whole path as well, without success

Comment: Its Lubuntu i repeat. Not Ubuntu if this helps.

Comment: Just tried this. This time it found the file but it showed a message saying "package architecture (amd64) doesn't match system (i386). Maybe i must install the 64bit version of Lubuntu. If  you have any other idea i'm glad to hear it. By Tuesday i will buy an ssd and install there the 64bit version (even if i have only 3gb of RAM). I will came back with news by then.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067668/installing-minecraft-on-a-32-bit-xubuntu-18-04-lts-installation Here it confirms that it needs an 64bit system so i will go with the 64bit soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps are as follows :

1. go to https://www.minecraft.net and log into your account.
2. then click on the minecraft dirt cube that says download.
3. then click on the big green button that says "DOWNLOAD FOR YOUR DISTRIBUTION"
4. then scroll down a tiny bit and click on ".deb package" in the middle of the paragraph that says "DEBIAN AND DEBIAN BASED DISTRIBUTIONS".
5. if you're using chrome have the download open with default as soon as it finishes downloading, otherwise run when downloading completes.
6. I should open the software center. click "install"
7. hit the windows/super key on your keyboard and type "Mine..." Minecraft will show up. once again log in an click "play latest..." it will download and run minecraft.

(minecraft on linux is 64 bit only)

Comment: On step 6 when i click "install" an error appears at the bottom saying "dependency resolution failed" and nothing happens on step 7.

Comment: I use 18.10 version cause its the only available version for 32bit. The 19.04 is 64bit version and i have only 3gb of RAM (i think that the 32bit version run smother on my device, but i haven't tried 64bit version yet). Anyway, by Tuesday i will buy and ssd and i will install there the 64bit version (19.04). I will came back with news by then.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067668/installing-minecraft-on-a-32-bit-xubuntu-18-04-lts-installation Here it confirms that it needs an 64bit system so i will go with the 64bit soon.